# In listview I click an audio to start but when I scroll I see other audios has stared too

Tags: android

I have a ListView of audios which have seek bar in it . When I click the play button of one of audios, it starts but when I scroll down I see that some other seekbars are also playing and when I scroll up again the first item that I clicked is no paused. I have searched a lot and it seems that there is a problem with position of item in list , the only solution I found was to use viewholder in adapter but it didn't work . does any one have a solution? thanks.

```
public class AudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

Context context;
boolean isPLaying = false;

public AudioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<News> array) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_news, array);
    this.context = context;

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView audioDuration;
    ImageView btnPlayStop;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Handler seekHandler;
    int audioCurrentPosition;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final News news = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_audio, parent, false);

        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.audioTitle);
        viewHolder.seekBar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(seek_bar);
        viewHolder.audioDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
        viewHolder.btnPlayStop = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayStop);
        viewHolder.mp = new MediaPlayer();
        viewHolder.seekHandler = new Handler();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(news.getTitle());

    viewHolder.mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.team);
    viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition = news.getAudioPosition();
    viewHolder.mp.seekTo(viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition * 1000);

    viewHolder.audioDuration.setText(ms);

    viewHolder.btnPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if ( !isPLaying) {

                viewHolder.mp.seekTo(viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition * 1000);
                //play
                isPLaying = true;
                viewHolder.btnPlayStop.setImageResource(ic_media_pause);

                viewHolder.mp.start();

                viewHolder.seekBar.setMax(  viewHolder.mp.getDuration() / 1000);

                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (  viewHolder.mp != null &&   viewHolder.mp.isPlaying()) {
                            int mCurrentPosition =  viewHolder.mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                            viewHolder.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                            viewHolder.seekHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                            news.setAudioPosition(  viewHolder.mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //pause
                isPLaying = false;
                viewHolder.btnPlayStop.setImageResource(ic_media_play);
                viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition =   viewHolder.mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                viewHolder.mp.pause();
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (  viewHolder.mp != null && fromUser) {
                //Change the seekbar with finger
                viewHolder.mp.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition = progress * 1000;
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //When mediaplayer finishes
            isPLaying = false;
            viewHolder.btnPlayStop.setImageResource(ic_media_play);
            viewHolder.audioCurrentPosition = 0;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Release your old `MediaPlayer` when you a new instance is started. For example:

```
protected void mediaplayerMethod(String filepath) {

Log.d(TAG, "mediaplayerMethod audio file path " + filepath);

if(mp != null){
    mp.release();
}
mp = null;

mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(AudioAdapter.this); // Important

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(AudioAdapter.this);

utils = new Utilities();

playSong(filepath);

}
```

**EDIT 1**

You can try the below code

```
public class SoundTest extends Activity {
private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[]={"test 1","test 2","test 3","test 4","test 5"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, lv_arr));

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    if (lv1.getItemAtPosition(position)=="test 1") {
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound1);
      mp.start();
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.release();
        }
      });
    }

    if (lv1.getItemAtPosition(position)=="test 2") {
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound2);
      mp.start();
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.release();
        }
      });
      }

    //And the rest of the audio 3,4,5.

    }
    });
}
}
```

The global variable `MediaPlayer` needs to be set `private static`. This has caught me several times.

Comment: It still has the problem when I scroll

Comment: I wrote list.setOnItemClickListener an put mediaplayer in it . but How should I set the seek bar progress

Comment: thanks , but I mean  where should I set seekbar in adapter or activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ViewHolder pattern, your views are being recycled and hence, your playing-indicator gets reused too...

Comment: without using viewholder it has this problem again